# Machine learning approach to add silences to translated subtitles

Tags: algorithm, audio, machine-learning, synchronization, neural-network

I have a data set of a video game subtitles in English and in French and the audio files for the English subtitles only. The English subtitle have silences specified in them that matches their respective audio file. For example,

```
[Silence 3] Some narrated text goes here. [Silence 2] Some more text goes here.
```

(The 3 in [Silence 3] represents the silence duration).

My task is to provide a program that adds the silences to the French subtitles so that I can output :

```
[Silence 3] Certains textes narratifs vont ici. [Silence 2] Un peu plus de texte va ici.
```

I already have the answers for the French subtitles which I am supposed to use to verify the effectiveness of my algorithm. I was thinking of doing a machine learning approach using the already given answer to teach my algorithm but I am not sure what would be the best type of algorithm or if this is the way to go in this case. I also find no use for the audio files. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Edit: Not all sentences behave like the example I gave earlier, sometimes the silence is in the middle of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would forget about machine learning approach and just divide the text into sentences.

```
sentence 1
sentence 2
SILENCE
sentence 3
SILENCE
```

Grab the corresponding translation, then insert silence in appropriate positions (after position 2 and 3).

Comment: The thing is, this is my final year project so I would be surprised the solution is that easy. Also, sometimes the silences are in the middle of a sentence. Although I could solve 90% of the cases they gave me in the data sheet using simple string comparison, I don't think this is what they expect from me.

Comment: Then I suggest you to write, that you are not trying to solve any problem here, but mostly want to find how to do a homework. Also it is nice to describe the full requirements, because it is impossible to guess what kind of data do you have and its peculiarities.

Comment: Well the problem I'm trying to solve is how to approach the problem, is machine learning too far fetched for this?

Comment: in my opinion yes. Now knowing that your `silence` can be anywhere, I would start looking into correspondence of words or phrases in both texts.